# Android PlayStore Subscription Testing : issue with purchase with same account

Tags: android

Am testing subscription in-app purchase [following the guidelines in the Android doc here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test). I did a purchase of an in-app product (test purchase) when logged into a particular Google Play account. Then, I logged off & logged back in to the same account. Now, when I try in-app purchase, it again says 'buy' (i.e. shows as if the purchase hasn't been done). Any idea why?

Comment: Are you logged into play store with it after relogin?

Comment: yes, @random ; that's right